# New Android phone with app in development distribution can't get location

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm developing an application with location. The app will be distributed ad hoc. The problem is that new Android phones can't detect the location. I need to open the Google Maps app, accept the terms and conditions, and after that, I open my app and everything is fine.

I assume that there is a problem with Google Play Services, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you using the Play Services' fused location provider? Or are you using `LocationManager`?

Comment: Can you add some more details?

Comment: Hello Daniel, Why do you need to take the user to the Google Maps app? Can you elaborate on "new android phones can't detect the location"? Do you just need to detect the user's location?

Comment: You're using getLastKnownLocation(), aren't you?  Don't use that-  it doesn't do what you think it does.  Read any of the dozens of posts on this website about how to actually get location.